# Simple way for removing all non word characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to remove all characters from string, using most simple way.
For example
from `"a,sd3 31ds"` to `"asdds"` 
I cad do it something like this:

```
"a,sd3 31ds".gsub(/\W/, "").gsub(/\d/,"")
# => "asdds"
```

but it looks a little bit awkward. Maybe it is possible to merge these rexegs in one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
"a,sd3 31ds".gsub(/(\W|\d)/, "")
```

Answer (score 12):

I would go for the regexp `/[\W\d]+/`. It is potentially faster than e.g. `/(\W|\d)/`.

```
require 'benchmark' 

N = 500_000
Regexps = [ "(\\W|\\d)", "(\\W|\\d)+", "(?:\\W|\\d)", "(?:\\W|\\d)+", 
            "\\W|\\d", "[\\W\\d]", "[\\W\\d]+" ]

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|  
  Regexps.each do | re_str |
    re = Regexp.new(re_str)
    x.report("/#{re_str}/:") { N.times { "a,sd3 31ds".gsub(re, "") }}
  end
end
```

gives (with ruby 2.0.0p195 [x64-mingw32])

```
                      user     system      total        real
/(\W|\d)/:        1.950000   0.000000   1.950000 (  1.951437)
/(\W|\d)+/:       1.794000   0.000000   1.794000 (  1.787569)
/(?:\W|\d)/:      1.857000   0.000000   1.857000 (  1.855515)
/(?:\W|\d)+/:     1.638000   0.000000   1.638000 (  1.626698)
/\W|\d/:          1.856000   0.000000   1.856000 (  1.865506)
/[\W\d]/:         1.732000   0.000000   1.732000 (  1.754596)
/[\W\d]+/:        1.622000   0.000000   1.622000 (  1.617705)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the regex "OR".

```
"205h2n0bn  r0".gsub(/\W|\d/, "")
```

will do the trick :)

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
"a,sd3 31ds".gsub(/\W|\d/,"")
```

You can always join regular expressions by `|` to express an "or".

Answer (score 4):

You can try this regex:

```
\P{L}
```

not Unicode letter, but I don't know, does Ruby support this class.

Answer (score 4):

A non regex solution:

```
"a,sd3 31ds".delete('^A-Za-z')
```

Comment: `"a,sd3[] 31ds".delete('^A-z')` => `"asd[]ds"`

Comment: @undur_gongor: Ah yes. I'll fix it.

Comment: @steenslag Isn't the part between the parenthesis the regex part? What you mean is 'A non `#gsub` solution' or am I wrong?